# ReferenceError: Chart is not defined with primeNg and angular 4

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I get the above error when I take out this line from my index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
```

Is there anyway to take out of the index.html and add the equivalent line in my systemjs.config.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You can define script in angular.json with the latest version of angular and for an old version of angular you can refer angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": ["./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"]
```

If your project is running and you are changing in file runtime they might not work `so stop the server and start again.`